# How to recover data that was encrypted with a revoked or expired key?

Tags: encryption, key-management

Do you know any processes for recovering data which has been encrypted with a revoked or expired encryption key after the encryption key becomes invalid?

Comment: Use the revoked or expired key.  A revoked or expired key is still valid for decryption.  Revocation and/or expiration generally means that you should not use it any longer, not that it will not work.

Comment: In what system are we talking here? How are you trying to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

The expire does not matter in that case. If you have the key you can still decrypt it.